# disabling background of document when certain div opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

,
HI,

I need some ones help with this, thank you in advance.

In my site i have that when the user clicks on a input box then a new div opens up on top of the input box in that exact place.

Now i need to add that when that div opens i need the background of the hole screen to become black with some opacity, i think it is called overlay.

some thing like i want you can find here:

> http://www.omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/

if you hover with the mouse over the div on the side that says "come work at splunk".

How can i do something like that with jquery or any thing else.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you thinking of a jquery/javascript modal dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [jQuery UI Dialog Modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal).

**Edit:** jQuery's Dialog method will give you a similar effect but is usually used for onclick events rather than mouseover/mouseout. Have a look at the javascript code on the page you linked (around line 356) and you'll see:

```
$('#splunkjobs').mouseenter(function() {
    // make element absolute, positioned over the top of the float and resize
    $('<div id="shade"></div>').
    appendTo('body').
    css('height', $(document).height()).
    animate({opacity: 0.6});
```

This essentially creates a  that covers the page and then fades it in.

I still think using a Dialog for your button is preferred (and much simpler).

Comment: i think this is what i need, any idea why it is not working for me?

Comment: just one problem, i am adding the shade background to a iframe, so when i do the above not the hole width of the iframe gets covered, if i scroll to the side it doesnt have it. any ideas how to fix this, i tried add 'css('width', $(document).width()).', didnt work

Answer (score 0):

this is caled 'modal', you can use jquery:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples

or if you still need more:
http://coderplus.com/2009/11/jquery-modal-boxes-to-improve-your-ui/

Comment: Thank you, but what i need is not anything very fancy, i dont want the div added to be gradable, it needs to be fixed in a certain position, that i have. all i need is to add that gray background to the body.